# Is there a merchant who sells shipments of wood?

Tags: fallout-4

I can't seem to get enough wood.

After some recent expansions to some of my settlements, I find myself running pretty low on wood these days.  I've been salvaging as much raw material as possible and have even taken to buying any junk that includes wood, but it takes a heck of a lot of brooms to make even one room in a settlement.

What I am *not* short on at the moment is caps.  So, is there a merchant somewhere who will give me a bunch of wood?  (For caps, of course.  I'm not above paying for it.)

Comment: Run out of *wood*? What? I have to wonder what your settlements look like. I don't think I've ever been short on wood for anything in any settlement at any point.

Comment: I'll have to take some screenshots, but I've walled in Sanctuary, Starlight, Greentop Nursery, and the Castle.  Oh, and I've built some buildings in Starlight including a penthouse in the sky as a vanity project.  Suffice it to say, I've spent a lot of raw materials.  :)

Comment: I've mostly been using pre-fab buildings to warehouse my settlers beds. Over the weekend I made some building piece by piece, and found I actually managed to run out of wood. That was mostly because I had barely scrapped anything, but I was definitely surprised how fast that burned through my supply.

Comment: So, I'm pretty sure the pre-fab buildings are a little leaner on the materials cost than building things panel by panel.  But it's much more fun to build your own buildings.  And by walling in some of my settlements and placing turrets at strategic places along the wall, I've managed to keep most of my settlements fairly well defended.

Comment: You probably already know this - but maybe other readers don't. You know if you connect your settlements with a supply chain you can share resources immediately. Wood might be the most common thing in the game, even virtually impossible to exhaust unless you're building sky scrapers in each settlement. I keep my resources tied to one main camp, then supply chain every other settlement to my main one. The only thing I tend to run low on is copper which you can get from all the broken lamps everywhere

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there are 3 vendors that will sell shipments of wood.

- Connie Abernathy, Abernathy Farm (50 units)
- Supervisor Greene, Graygarden (50 units)
- Moe Cronin, Diamond City (100 units)

Besides that, the best way to get wood is by scrapping all trees, wood piles, stumps, and fences in settlements. Larger trees typically scrap for 20-30 units of wood apiece.

Comment: Small groups of trees (which are a single game object) are generally scrap-able for more than single large trees. Don't neglect those

Answer (score 16):

[**Moe in Diamond city**](http://fallout4.wiki/junk/shipment-of-wood-100) has wood shipments for sale.

[image]

[**There is also a list here**](http://fallout4.wiki/materials/wood) of things that can be scrapped for some wood

Comment: Gave you an up-vote too for the list of items that can be scrapped.  Not really useful for me since I'm basically the wasteland trash collector, but it may be useful for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

Although you *could* leave your settlement to shop for wood (or other supplies, like steel), I find it much easier to establish a [Trading Shop](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Trading_post) inside your settlement instead.

The Trading Shop I built in Sanctuary sells "Shipments of Wood" in addition to other goods, including junk items that contain rare components like nuclear material, oil, etc.

Plus, constructing and manning a Trading Shop gives a +10 overall happiness bonus, and it generates caps.  You also don't have to haul your massive mutifruit/purified water stash any further than across the street.  It's basically a win no matter how you slice it!